# VerifyData: Assettion Error. How to make test pass

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

**data.json**

```
[
     {
        "id": "trololo_id",
        "email": "nasir1985@hotmail.com",
        "roles": ["admin", "member"],
        "apiKey": ["c0ca4bf0-687a-4eed-a96d-4589bb0f7347"],
        "profile": {
            "dob": "1992-09-10",
            "name": "Rachel Sheppard",
            "about": "There are no rules of architecture for a castle in the clouds.;Gilbert K. Chesterton;imagination",
            "address": "11 Seagate",
            "company": "Verbus",
            "location": {
                "lat": -79.066,
                "lon": -85.69855
            }
        },
        "username": "rachel92",
        "createdAt": "2011-01-26T22:11:43.564Z",
        "updatedAt": "2011-01-26T22:11:43.564Z"
     }
 ]
```

**Request**

Method: POST

URL: https://reqres.in/api/users

Body:

```
{   
    "email": "{{email}}",
    "roles": ["{{roles}}"], 
    "profile": {
        "name": "{{name}}",
        "address": "{{address}}",
        "company": "{{company}}"
    }
}
```

Pre-req:

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("name", data["profile"]["name"]);
pm.collectionVariables.set("address", data["profile"]["address"]);
pm.collectionVariables.set("company", data["profile"]["company"]);
```

Tests:

```
pm.test("Status code is 201", function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(201);
});

pm.test("Verify data", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.email).to.eql(data['email']);
    pm.expect(jsonData.profile).to.eql(data['profile']);    
    pm.expect(jsonData.profile.address).to.eql(data['profile']['address']);
    pm.expect(jsonData.profile.company).to.eql(data['profile']['company']);
});
```

Response

```
{
    "email": "nasir1985@hotmail.com",
    "roles": [
        "admin,member"
    ],
    "profile": {
        "name": "Rachel Sheppard",
        "address": "11 Seagate",
        "company": "Verbus"
    },
    "id": "209",
    "createdAt": "2023-09-17T09:23:11.682Z"
}
```

Why is there an assertion error and how can I fix it?

**Images:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try using data[0]["profile"]["name"]; currently data["profile"] is undefined.

Comment: Thank you. If you organise that as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is on the prerequest script (`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "name")`), so the issue is on this line

```
pm.collectionVariables.set("name", data["profile"]["name"]);
```

which means that `data["profile"]` is undefined. Looking at the mapping of `data.json`, the correct syntax should be `data[0]["profile"]["name"]`, as `data` is an array of objects.